# Create multiple subfolders with different parent folders CSV - Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server, powershell-ise

I'm trying to create multiple sub folders for different parent directories. I have a CSV file with almost 700 folders.
I have 4 columens in my CSV

> Column A serial code (codigo)
>
> Column B course (materia)
>
> Column C faculty the course belongs to (facultad)
>
> Column D career that have that course (carrera)

I have the following code for that

```
$materias = Import-Csv C:\Materias.csv

foreach{$EstMaterias in $materias)
{
    $path = "C:\" 
    $codigo = $EstMaterias.codigo
    $materia = $EstMaterias.materia
    $facultad = $EstMaterias.facultad
    $carrera = $EstMaterias.carrera

    New-Item -Path("$path\$facultad\$carrera\$mateira") -Type directory
}
```

I'm not sure how to filter thee subfolders so that the careers are created inside their correct faculty and courses inside their correct career. With the code I run right now all courses are created inside the faculties and inside all of the careers.

Comment: Can you provide a sample csv with a few line (not the whole file) and the actual and expected result?

Comment: this is a picture of the csv https://ibb.co/6P9F9Rn

Comment: this is what it should look like https://ibb.co/FbxPmLL

Comment: First - please do not add additional information as comments. Add them to your question instead. And second - [a picture of code or sample data is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) ...

Comment: Is that a type $mateira instead of $materia ?

Comment: You don't use `$codigo = $EstMaterias.codigo` and you have typing error here `("$path\$facultad\$carrera\$mateira")`. You typed in $mateira instead of `$materia`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `$codigo = $EstMaterias.codigo`, and you have typing error here `"$path\$facultad\$carrera\$mateira"`. You typed in `$mateira` instead of `$materia`.

```
$materias = Import-Csv C:\Materias.csv

$path = "C:"

foreach ($EstMaterias in $materias) {
    $codigo = $EstMaterias.codigo # What is this? You don't use it here.
    $materia = $EstMaterias.materia
    $facultad = $EstMaterias.facultad
    $carrera = $EstMaterias.carrera

    New-Item -Path "$path\$facultad\$carrera\$materia" -Type directory
}
```